# Sorting an array using count of an array property in an object element

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, routes

I have an array of objects $routes, which holds all the Fs_Controller_Router_Route objects of my project.

Every Fs_Controller_Router_Route object has a `controller`, `action`, `params` (array), `name` and `alias` properties.

Every property can be accessed using a get Method (getAction, getController, getParams, getName and getAlias).

As you can see in the following array, the params property is an array, containing the params of the current route..

```
  array (size=6)
      'home' => 
        object(Fs_Controller_Router_Route)[3]
          private '_controller' => string 'index' (length=5)
          private '_action' => string 'index' (length=5)
          private '_params' => 
            array (size=2)
              ':name' => string 'Michael' (length=7)
              ':family_name' => string 'Corleone' (length=4)
          private '_name' => string 'home' (length=4)
          private '_alias' => string '/:name/:family_name' (length=19)
      'login' => 
        object(Fs_Controller_Router_Route)[4]
          private '_controller' => string 'index' (length=5)
          private '_action' => string 'login' (length=5)
          private '_params' => 
            array (size=0)
              empty
          private '_name' => string 'login' (length=5)
          private '_alias' => string '/login' (length=6)
      'signup' => 
        object(Fs_Controller_Router_Route)[5]
          private '_controller' => string 'index' (length=5)
          private '_action' => string 'signup' (length=6)
          private '_params' => 
            array (size=2)
              ':serial' => string 'dh3kddooo' (length=9)
              ':token' => string '304888030' (length=9)
          private '_name' => string 'signup' (length=6)
          private '_alias' => string '/signup/:token/:serial' (length=22)
      'about' => 
        object(Fs_Controller_Router_Route)[7]
          private '_controller' => string 'index' (length=5)
          private '_action' => string 'index' (length=5)
          private '_params' => 
            array (size=2)
              ':serial' => string 'dh3kddooo' (length=9)
              ':token' => string '304888030' (length=9)
          private '_name' => string 'about' (length=5)
          private '_alias' => string '/about/:serial/:token' (length=6)
```

What I want to do, is to sort the objects ascendantly, using the number of params for every object.

I didn't manage to do that using this code .. I simply don't know how to add the count params part to the array_multisort function

```
array_multisort(array_map('count', $routes), SORT_ASC, $routes);
```

Comment: have you considered using `usort` and just writing a simple compare function? http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.usort.php

Comment: I tried using array_multisort (because I'm used to do it) and I didn't think about usort , thanks a lot... I didn't think about it. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Andresch Serj in his comment .. I found the solution, and it works

```
usort($routes, function($a,$b){

            if(count($b->getParams()) > count($a->getParams())){
                return 1;
            }else{
                return 0;
            }

        });
```

Thank you